# Getting error while installing Express from windows command prompt

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install

I have successfully installed nodejs in C:\Program File. Nodejs and npm are also working fine by checking version of both.

Description and version info of softwares/hardwares I'm using as below

**OS:-** Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, 64-bit

**RAM:-** 4GB

**Nodejs:-** version 7.4.0

**npm:-** version 4.0.5

**java:-** version 1.8.0_121

Now while I'm trying to install express from cmd using **`npm install --save express`** command,following error is coming.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   'express' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.5
3 info using node@v7.4.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData express
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData express
9 silly mapToRegistry name express
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: 'express',
12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: 'express',
12 silly mapToRegistry   name: 'express',
12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
13 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express
14 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express
15 verbose request no auth needed
16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 7:15:42 PM
17 verbose request id 90eb0dc94f842d2f
18 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
19 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
20 info attempt registry request try #2 at 7:15:52 PM
21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
23 info attempt registry request try #3 at 7:16:52 PM
24 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for express { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
25 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 443 }
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
27 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
29 silly install printInstalled
30 verbose stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
30 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
30 verbose stack     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
30 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
31 verbose cwd D:\ExpressJS Apps\ExpressDemo
32 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
33 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "express"
34 error node v7.4.0
35 error npm  v4.0.5
36 error code EAI_AGAIN
37 error errno EAI_AGAIN
38 error syscall getaddrinfo
39 error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
40 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
40 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I already searched it in stack overflow and also get a solution of it but for the **linux operating system**. So please don't mark this question duplicate as there is no solution for **windows OS** for this issue

**EDIT:-**

When I'm trying to run `npm install` command following error coming

```
D:\ExpressJS Apps\ExpressDemo>npm install
npm WARN express-demo@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Comment: It looks like this error is related to DNS. Have you tried `ping registry.npmjs.org` from `cmd`?

Comment: @shambalambala I just check your command in cmd. following issue is coming "Ping request could not find host registry.npmjs.org. Please check the name and try again."

Answer (score 0):

After searching lots regarding this issue on internet for last 2 days and consulting with my organization's IT expert team and my project mate, I finally resolved this issue.

First of all I'm developing app using node.js and express at my organization that means I'm working behind the corporate firewall. That's why I'm getting above issues mention in question section. So, I just follow the below step to resolve it

Open your command prompt and hit the following three command at your cmd.

```
npm set config registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
npm set config proxy "http://username:password@host:port/"
npm set config strict-ssl false
```

After entering above 3 command in command prompt , a file, **.npmrc**, will be created under **C:\user\your_user_name** directory.

Now I'm able to download and install all  the necessary files including **express.js** from command line.